# Como centralizar o texto em uma MessageBox?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Neste momento tenho este código:

```
MessageBox.Show("Verificação da password incorreta \n Insira novamente");
```

E o *output* fica assim:

```
Verificação da password incorreta
Insira novamente
```

Como faço para o *output* ficar centralizado no na `MessageBox`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não tem como. O componente não foi desenhado para isto.

A solução é usar outra coisa. Pode ser uma caixa de mensagem que você desenvolve.

Tem alguns [exemplos no Code Project](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/601900/FlexibleMessageBox-A-flexible-replacement-for-the) ([também](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17253/A-Custom-Message-Box)) e [no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8869984/221800) e [na MSDN](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Custom-MessageBox-3d034ec6?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Nenhum faz o que deseja, mas dá uma ideia do que precisa fazer, mas tem [uma que está próximo](https://www.mindstick.com/Articles/872/custom-message-box-in-c-sharp-dot-net).

Outra solução é não centralizar, pense se realmente precisa disto.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score -1):

```
MsgBox "O RELÓGIO" _
    & Chr(13) & "Cassiano Ricardo" _
    & Chr(13) _
    & Chr(13) & Chr(9) & "Diante de coisa tão doida" _
    & Chr(13) & Chr(9) & "Conservemo-nos serenos" _
    & Chr(13) & Chr(9) & "Cada minuto da vida" _
    & Chr(13) & Chr(9) & "Nunca é mais, é sempre menos" _
    & Chr(13) _
    & Chr(13) & Chr(9) & "Ser é apenas uma face" _
    & Chr(13) & Chr(9) & "Do não ser, e não do ser" _
    & Chr(13) & Chr(9) & "Desde o instante em que se nasce" _
    & Chr(13) & Chr(9) & "Já se começa a morrer.", 16, _
    "                         M   E   N   S   A   G   E   M"
```

Comment: Bem vindo ao stackoverflow Serafim. Você poderia adicionar maiores detalhes sobre a sua resposta? Fale um pouco sobre o método que você utilizou, respostas com apenas código podem não ser muito atrativas

Comment: Você poderia ao menos adicionar uma breve explicação do código acima?

Comment: Diletos desenvolvedores, 

     Faço uma concatenação do texto, quebrado para as instruções ficarem esteticamente claras,com os códigos ASCii:
Chr(13) = "pula linha"; e
Chr(9)   = "Indenta texto. 

     Depois da primeira vírgula uso o código  16 ("Exibe o ícone Mensagem Crítica.") e depois da última vírgula, não tem jeito, calibro com espaços para escrever os títulos, ok? 

     Uso versos antes do "End Sub" para saber se a programação está executando certo e para interromper e ver se as variáveis empregadas estão com os valores desejados.

Atenciosamente, 

Serafim